# Cannot find a differ supporting object when adding a class to div

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have created a simple ngBootstrap modal window, as follows:

```
<ng-template #alertModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header" [ngClass]="titleStyle">
    <h4 class="modal-title">
      <i id="icon" class="fa fa-1x" [ngClass]="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{title}}
    </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true" [ngStyle]="titleStyle"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" [innerHtml]="body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

and I apply classes to the title dynamically like this:

```
this.titleStyle = 'bg-warning text-white';
this.icon = 'fa-exclamation-circle';
```

So adding classes to the icon element works fine, but adding the classes to the first div element fails like this: (If I replace the titeStyle string with '' it shows without error, but without formatting):

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'bg-warning text-white' at KeyValueDiffers.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.KeyValueD

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ngClass is not causing it to fail. Looks like you are assigning the same `titleStyle` to the `ngStyle` directive here,

```
<span aria-hidden="true" [ngStyle]="titleStyle"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Is that intended?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you have written.  I added classes to 2 different elements using 2 different variables, both using [ngClass]=

Comment: That is okay, but how about the line mentioned above, specifically this: `[ngStyle]="titleStyle"`. You are assigning the class names to the `ngStyle` property there. Is that intended?

Comment: That's not intentional (I might have been playing with styles) - but I don't think it will affect the operation of the page

Comment: Just give it a try if you can. I don't think that is a valid assignment for a `style` as those styles are not likely recognizable. See [this](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

Comment: I think that this is a correct answer. We will need a reproduce scenario in a plunker or similar if it still doesn't work for now.

Comment: OK - I removed the [ngStyle]="titleStyle} from the i element, and that worked.  But why?  I still don't get WHY that's not acceptable.  Can't 2 elements bind to the same variable for ngClass?  (Or are you saying those styles cannot be applied to an i element?

Comment: The syntax for adding `ngClass` and `ngStyles` are slightly different eventhough it looks the similar. Yes, you can add classes dynamically as a space-separated array of strings as in `<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>` (source [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)), if it has to be added no matter what. But if a certain number of classes only needs to be added based on a condition, then you need to use something like this, `<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>`.

Comment: Were you able to try it out without the `ngStyle` assignment mentioned above?

Comment: Yes - it worked and I will accept answer.  Was they key to your answer that the styles were not applicable to an 'i' element?

Comment: First of all, you had the `ngStyle` applied to a `<span>` not an `<i>`. That doesn't realy matter in any case though. 'Style' and 'Class' are different in that classes are meant to hold a set of styles that can be reused elsewhere if needed. It also helps in separating the `html ` content from presentation/styles. `ngStyle` is meant to hold only the specific the `style`s (like `height`, `heigh.px`, `height.em`, `font-style` etc.) and not the class-names/classes that contains a set of styles. `ngClass` is used to refer to such classes.